# How to define a free variable

Tags: python, scope, free-variable

I am currently reading the book Fluent Python - Luciano Ramalho (a great book IMO).

In the chapter about decorators and closures, there is a following piece of code:

```
def make_averager():
    series = []

    def averager(value):
        series.append(value)
        total = sum(series)
        return total/len(series)
    return averager


avg = make_averager()
```

So in this case, `series` is a free variable, and I can verify this by printing

```
>>> avg.__code__.co_varnames
('new_value', 'total')
>>> avg.__code__.co_freevars
('series',)
```

But when I tried refactoring the `make_averager()`:

```
def make_averager():
    series = []
    total = 0
    count = 0

    def averager(value):
        total += value
        count += 1
        return total/count
    return averager

avg = make_averager()
```

either `series`, `total` or `sum` is considered a free_variable. Instead, `total` and `sum` are now local variables (?) since `avg.__code__.co_varnames` returns `('value', 'total', 'count')` and `avg.__code__.co_freevars` returns `()`.

So now `series` is now no longer a free-variable in the scope of `averager`, unless I add

```
series.append(value)
```

inside `averager(value)`. This is understandable since I don't call `series` at all inside `averager(value)`, but I couldn't understand what's happening with those 2 variables.

Why are `total` and `count` not considered as free-variables, and how do I assign them as free-variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## nonlocal total, count

```
def averager(value):
    nonlocal total
    nonlocal count
    total += value
    count += 1
    return total/count
```

##### Why does nonlocal make them free variables?

Without nonlocal, `total += value` assigns to `total` which by default creates a local variable. Since `total` is in the local scope of the function `averager`, it is no longer a free variable.

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution. But could you explain why `series` is considered a `nonlocal` in the first approach, while `total` and `sum` aren't in the second?

Comment: You never assign to the `series` variable.(e.g. `series = []`) `series.append` translates to find object held by `series` variable. Is `series` in local scope? No. try outer scope, yes. Now ask series object for method `append` so that I can call it.